# SPeL in thymeleaf: use object properties

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-el

I have registered a custom PermissionEvaluator and would like to pass object properties to the hasPermission method from Thymeleaf.

This works fine:

```
<span sec:authorize="hasPermission('A', 'ConfidentialDocument', 'read')">
    XXXX
</span>
```

This fails:

```
<span sec:authorize="hasPermission(${device.id}, 'ConfidentialDocument', 'read')">
    XXXX
</span>
```

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression
>   [hasPermission(${device.id}, 'ConfidentialDocument', 'read')] @15:
>   EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'

What am I doing wrong? (device is definitly set).

Answer (score 0):

Found an solution:

```
<span th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasPermission(''__${device}__'' , ''read'')')}">
   xxx
</span>
```